# what are the packages in Android?

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me what are the packages available in Android, and which package is frequently used and for what purpose they are used. Anybody please help me regarding in this.

Thanks in Advance,
Tilsan.

Comment: Accept some answers to your previous questions! You will gain reputation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

Answer (score 1):

find your answers here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary.html